# Pass parameter from JSP to Interceptor

Tags: jsp, struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

How can i catch this parameter in my Struts2 Custom Interceptor, send from a JSP page ?

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsontable">
    <s:param name="gridName">gridTableID</s:param>
</s:url>
  <sjg:grid
        id="gridTableID"

        caption="Customer Examples (Local Data)"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        rowNum="-1"
        hidegrid="true"
....
```

Edit:
My custom stack:

```
<interceptors>
            <interceptor name="logingInterceptor" class="com.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor"></interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="newStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="logingInterceptor" />
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <default-interceptor-ref name="newStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2: if your interceptor can't get the request parameters, I suggest an atomic approach to the problem. Try small steps, resolve problems one by one.
In your case, i'll try as follows:

1) Put a debug "hello interceptor" inside your interceptor, to see if the call to your action is actually passing THROUGH your custom interceptor.

If not: check your settings (interceptor, interceptors-stack, packages, actions etc).

If yes:

2) Put a normal variable in the form you are posting in a classic way (not ajax or something, just a `<s:hidden name="foo" value="blabla"/>` variable inside your form in the JSP, posted with an `<s:submit` button to your action (the actiop mapped for using the interceptor stack with your custom interceptor).
Try to print out the value of that variable from the interceptor.

If variable is null:
check your action mappings again, use Firebug Net module to see if the parameters is actually posted out, etc.

If variable is read:

then the problem is in the variable of the JQGrid, check the way you are referencing it in the JSP and what is going out of the page with Firebug again.

Etc...

I suggest you to use a new JSP with only your stuff inside, with a new action for displaying and receiving the result, with an empty execute()... just a very very tiny skeleton to test your code being sure nothing external is messing up the worflow...

---

EDIT: your Interceptors configuration seems fine (except for `defaultStack` instead of `default-stack`, but I'm pretty sure it's the same).

Are all of your Actions inside the same `<package>` in which the `<interceptors>` is defined ?

---

Why on the Interceptor and not in the Action ? How do you need to handle that data ?

By the way, this is the code:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

   final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
   HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);

   String gridName = (String) request.getParameter("gridName");

   /* do something */

   return invocation.invoke();
}
```

Comment: Then i'll check 1) The Inteceptor Stack you're using, maybe you are not using ParamInterceptor; 2) Use NET Firebug module to see if the parameter is actually being outputted by the page in the request. Post your struts configuration for more help...

Comment: i need this to persist my grid settings(about 50 grids in the project) to the database, in case the user changes the grid layout and leaves the page, all setting are gone to be persisted. i changed little bit my tactic. First i was going to identify every grid with parameter, i changed my mind. Now i will save/load the grid settings from database when the user is logging in. I believe its a better approach then the params way. In the end it didn't work with the parameters( the are always null, i don't know why). I believe this should work, and the problem is with my interceptors. Many Thanks

Comment: If you save your grid settings on login, you will never update the grid settings O_o you should save them on logout, but logout is difficult to intercept. For the null variable, see the edited answer (i'm editing right now). Thanks for accepting it.

Comment: the grid setting are already saved in cookies, i need only to updated the values if if necessary. You answer helped a lot, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me in struts 2.0.14.

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
            ActionConfig config  = ai.getProxy().getConfig();  
            Map parameters       = config.getParams();  
            String menuId        = (String)parameters.get("empName");
```